Sharing ductwork between a Gas Furnace and seperate A/C evap. Unit
I have a 1,200 sq. Ft two story home with two heat pump systems, one for each floor. The downstairs system is a ductless system and the upstairs is a ducted system in the attic. The AC in the summer works great for both systems but it gives poor heat in the winter.
I want to put in a forced air gas furnace to condition both floors as aux. Heat. Installing duct for the first floor isn't a problem but I want to know if I can share the exsisting ductwork in the attic to condition the second floor if I use motorized dampers and tees.
